# php file status cache - length of cache

Tags: php, caching

When using the file functions php has a file status cache, Though reading the documentation, Im not clear on the length of the cache (TTL)

> For instance, if the same file is being checked multiple times within
>   a single script

from http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Is it only ever in the length of the script ? so if a script called many times which does a `file_exists` does that do a stat for each time or is the cache used ? does the amount of php processes' matter ? eg one process has the result cached, but another one doesn't ?

If its not the php cache, does the OS / File system cache come in to play ? Assuming the file is not written to between script calls ?

Comment: It is longer than the length of the scripts for sure. I would like to know this answer too. Here is some more information about it, but sadly does not give the TTL. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28790